# Where can I buy a filter for UV photography in Europe? (sub 400 nm)

Tags: filters, uv, online-shopping

Does anyone know where one can purchase filters for UV photography in Europe?

These are the opposite of standard UV filters - these block visible light and only allow UV to pass through.

All I could find is the raw glass itself, nothing finished into a filter with threads.

Answer (score 3):

I had never heard of UV photography, how cool...

Anyhow, you can find them.

http://www.adorama.com/1/1/168553-peca-62mm-9-filter-kit-fk62.html has a UV filter in the kit, a Wratten 18A.

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/8219-REG/B_W_65011796_77mm_UV_Black.html ($200) is a B+W 403 filter.

I found this with good google-fu.

Take the filter types (Kodak Wratten 18A, B+W 403, Hoya U-340, Baader U-Filter and Kenko U-360) and put them into google along with a common thread size, say 77mm. And start clicking on the hits.

Or you can build your own filter, I just found this link. http://www.instructables.com/id/Photography-in-the-Ultraviolet-spectrum/ basically they take an incandescent black light, break it, and rig up something to put the glass over your camera lens. Might be tough to get a piece large enough for a big DSLR lens though.

And show us what you shoot!